# Login form in VB.NET doesn't allow user to login after they've entered login details incorrectly before entering the correct login details

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a multi-level access login form made in VB.NET that uses an Access database in the back end.

If the user tries to log in when there is nothing entered in either of the text boxes (presses the log in button with nothing entered into either of the text boxes) and then tries to log in after entering their correct  details, it allows it.

However, when the user enters either the username or password wrong, it will not allow them to log in after they have entered the correct details.

I am also having a problem where there is no case sensitivity (as long as the password has the correct characters in the correct order it doesn't matter if it is in upper case or lower case).

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class frmLogin
    Private DBCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                         "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NewHotel.mdb;")

    Private Sub btnLogIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogIn.Click
        If txtUsername.Text = "" Or txtPass.Text = "" Then
            lblErrorEmpty.Visible = True
        Else
            Try
                DBCon.Open()
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblEmployees WHERE [Username] = @Usernname AND [Pass] = @Pass", DBCon)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text.Trim
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPass.Text.Trim

                    Dim DBDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim DT As New DataTable
                    DBDA.Fill(DT)

                    If DT.Rows(0)("Type") = "Manager" Then
                        frmHomeManager.Show()
                    ElseIf DT.Rows(0)("Type") = "Receptionist" Then
                        frmHomeReceptionist.Show()
                    End If
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                lblErrorMatch.Visible = True
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare connections outside of the method where they are used. Connections need to be closed and disposed. `Using...End Using` blocks handle this even when there is an error.

I have separated the user interface code from the database code. This makes the code easier to maintain

For OleDb the `.Add` method for parameters will help. Don't open the connection until directly before the `.Execute`. You are only retrieving a single piece of data so `.ExecuteScalar` should do the trick.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\NewHotel.mdb;"

Private Sub btnLogIn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogIn.Click
    If txtUsername.Text = "" OrElse txtPass.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill in both User Name and Password")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim UserType As Object
    Try
        UserType = GetUserType(txtUsername.Text.Trim, txtPass.Text.Trim)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    If UserType Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("No record found")
    ElseIf UserType.ToString = "Manager" Then
        frmHomeManager.Show()
    ElseIf UserType.ToString = "Receptionist" Then
        frmHomeReceptionist.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show($"{UserType} is not listed.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetUserType(UserName As String, Password As String) As Object
    Dim Type As Object
    Using DBCon As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr),
        cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Type FROM tblEmployees WHERE [Username] = @Usernname AND [Pass] = @Pass", DBCon)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Password
        DBCon.Open()
        Type = cmd.ExecuteScalar.ToString
    End Using
    Return Type
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your check for the password is case insensitive, because you are storing the password directly and the database is case insensitive.

Your major problem is that you shouldn’t be storing the password in the database, you should be storing a cryptographically secure hash of the password in the database.  This will require more work, but will be much safer.

You don’t have enough details to say why you can’t make a second attempt.  I will say for reading a single record, I wouldn’t use a data table.